# $L^1$ vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $l^1$ is the collection of sequences $x=x_k$ of real numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|$ is finite. 
Show that $l^1$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and infinite dimension.

**Answer:**
I can show that this is a subspace of the set of all sequences. But I'm struggling with the proof of infinite dimension. I feel like the cantors argument might help. But couldn't proceed with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the set of sequences $e_k$ that are 0 everywhere except for the $k$-th place is a set of linearly independent vectors. They do not form a basis for $l^1$, though, since an (Hamel) basis for it must be uncountable.

Comment: aha! So as we have infinite number of linearly independent elements, we cannot have a finite dimension..Is that so?

Comment: Exactly, as any set of linearly independent vectors can be extended to a basis, so any basis must be larger than that.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Fun fact: the general statement “Every vector space has a basis” is in fact equivalent to the Axiom of Choice — one implication is a nice application of Zorn, the other is a result of Blass. Even if the specific instance of the theorem for $l^1$ isn't equivalent to AC, I still think it might be equivalent to some weaker but still independent form of choice, so we will never be able to give explicitly an Hamel basis for $l^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the elements $e_k$ of $\ell^1$ which are zero for every index save for $k$, at which they are 1.  They are linearly independent.

Comment: So do you say that this mentioned set of all $e_ks$ is a basis for $l^1$?

Comment: They are not a basis for $\ell^1$.

Comment: A vector space with an infinite linearly independent subset is infinite dimensional.